# Salesforce1 - Inconsistent layouts for new record

Tags: salesforce1-app, page-layout

I am using v7.0 of Salesforce1, wit a sandbox org which is on Winter 15.  There seem to be two ways to create a new object.  For example, for Accounts, I can do one of the following:

1. Click on the Accounts tab in the left column, which brings up the standard SFDC1 Account page.  This show Recent Accounts and recent views, and also has a  'New' button on the right.  Clicking this button brings up a page for creating a new Account whose fields come from the standard Page Layout configured for the user profile/record type.
2. Go to the Feed standard page, and at the bottom, click on the red circle with 3 dots to bring up Actions.  From here, click on the action to create a new Account.  Now it brings up a page whose fields come from the Global Action layout.

This seems to be an inconsistency, and this could be difficult to explain to business, non-technical users.  We would either like to be able to hide the New button, or use the same layout for both ways. Has anyone figured out how to do this?